# Does objective c support private inheritance of protocol

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

Can a protocol can be inherited privately so that in next inheritance level this should not be accessed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C has no “private inheritance” (or “private conformance”) the way C++ does.

You can conform to a protocol without advertising your conformance in your header file.  For example, you can conform to `NSCoding` “secretly” if you put this above your `@implementation` statement in your `.m` file:

```
@interface MyObject () <NSCoding>
@end
```

That declares a *class extension* that adds the `NSCoding` protocol to the `MyObject` class.

However, anyone (including a subclass) can ask whether you adopt the protocol:

```
[[MyObject class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]
// returns YES

[[MySubObject class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]
// also returns YES, if MySubObject is a subclass of MyObject
```

and anyone can send an `NSCoding` message to a `MyObject` by casting the object first:

```
[(id<NSCoding>)someObject encodeWithCoder:someCoder]
```

And if you make a subclass of `MyObject`, and your subclass also declares that it conforms to `NSCoding`, then it almost certainly needs to call `[super encodeWithCoder:]` from its own `encodeWithCoder:` method.

Comment: by inherited privately" i mean that if I have inherited a protocol "ProtocolBase"  so  that its callback should be the same object (class A), but when we are inheriting this class to another class suppose B then b should not get the protocol function overloaded

Comment: @vinsi I don't understand your comment.  Please edit your original question and explain there.

Comment: @rob mayoff in short  suppose we have 3 classes base,a,b  a inherits base  and have base methods over rides and b inherits a   normally b can override base method inherited from a and i want to block the class b from overriding the base method inherited through a

Comment: In Objective-C, you cannot prevent `b` from overriding any method of `a`.  The language allows `b` to override any method of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible because of the language design.

Moreover, as any method could be override, you can't ever be sure that your called method if from the right class.

There may be some hack which permit to directly *invoke* the method you want, but it's not that easy and may even not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol or otherwise, there is no way to stop methods being overridden by subclasses

[[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2864317/916299)